# How to run java application in Windows command prompt background?

Tags: java, powershell, batch-file, cmd, sh

We have a java application and written a shell script to launch this application in Linux.
Same way we written a batch file in Windows.We want to execute multiple instance of this application so we are using & in Linux shell script to execute the java process in background. Then your can use the same terminal to launch one more application and so on. We want to achieve the same in Windows. We also need to pass parameters to this launcher script.

Below is the launcher script for Linux , we need the equivalent Windows batch/cmd script.
The requirement is , user should be able to launch multiple times from the same terminal as like below.
Note: It will be good, if have simple solution in batch/cmd file not interested in power shell.

```
> app-launcher.sh 100 test
> app-launcher.sh 200 test
> app-launcher.sh 200 test1

#!/bin/sh

java  -classpath "thirdparty1.jar":"thirdparty1.jar" com.myapp.Main & 
sleep 2 && 
exit 0
```

Comment: Type `start /?` for starting programs in unusual ways. It is also the help for usual ways of starting programs that don't use `start`. NOTE: First set of quotes on the line will be taken as the window title.

Comment: is there any other way to launch without start / ...?

Comment: What's wrong with using `start`?

Comment: nothing wrong ..it deviates from Linux ..User has to remember this command